# Calculating $E(1+M_t)^2\int_0^t M_s^2 ds$ and $E(1+M_t)^2\int_0^t M_s^2 dM_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $ M= (M_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Standard Brownian Motion. I would like to calculate

$$E\left[(1+M_t)^2\int_0^t M_s^2 ds\right]$$ and $$E\left[(1+M_t)^2\int_0^t M_s^2 dM_s\right].$$

For the first one, I tried to use Fubini's theorem, but I get a strange result. I think I'm calculating wrongly
$$
E\int_0^t M_t^2M_s^2 d s
$$

For the first one, I use Itô's formula:
$$\int_0^t M_s^2 dM_s = \frac{1}{3}M_t^3 -\int_0^t M_s ds,$$
ant then again Fubini...

Am I doing it right? Is there other way? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the calculation of the first part, maybe consider $M_t^2 M_s^2 = (M_t - M_s + M_s)^2 M_s^2 = (M_t - M_s)^2 M_s^2 + M_s^4 + 2(M_t - M_s) M_s^3$ and use the fact that the increment are independent.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be doing it correctly. In the first case, you can use the Tonelli theorem rather than the Fubini theorem, because the integrand of the double-integral $(1+M_t)^2M_s^2$ is non-negative a.s., therefore we may interchange integrals, and the first one equals :
$$
E\left[(1+M_t)^2\int_0^t M_s^2 ds\right] = \int_0^t E\left[(1+M_t^2)M_s^2\right]ds
$$

To evaluate the inner integral is a standard exercise in independence and stationarity of increments, as mentioned in a comment : indeed, \begin{align}
(1+M_t^2)M_s^2 & = M_s^2 + ((M_t-M_s)+M_s)^2M_s^2 \\& = M_s^2 + (M_t-M_s)^2M_s^2 + M_s^4 + 2(M_t-M_s)M_s^3
\end{align}

and therefore by linearity of expectations :
\begin{align}
E[(1+M_t^2)M_s^2] & = \color{blue}{E[M_s^2]} + \color{green}{E[(M_t-M_s)^2M_s^2]} + \color{red}{E[M_s^4]} + \color{fuchsia}{E[2(M_t-M_s)M_s^3]} \\
\\ & = \color{blue}{s} + \color{green}{E[(M_t-M_s)^2]E[M_s^2]} + \color{red}{E[N(0,s)^4]} +  \color{fuchsia}{E[2(M_t-M_s)]E[M_s^3]} \\
&= \color{blue}{s} + \color{green}{(t-s)s} + \color{red}{3s^2}+\color{fuchsia}{0}
\\ &= \underline{\mathbf{s + ts + 2s^2}}
\end{align}

and now $\int_0^t (s+ts+2s^2)ds$ is easy to calculate.

> Key takeaway : Apply Fubini while looking out for Tonelli (which makes things so much easier!), and use independence of increments for taking expectations of polynomials of Brownian motion evaluated at various points.

---

For the second one, you have to apply the Ito formula as you have done, in order to simplify $\int_0^t M_s^2 dM_s$, with $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$. (The use of the formula is justified since the initial process is Brownian motion, obviously an Ito process, and $f$ is smooth)
\begin{align}
\frac{M_s^3}3 = \int_0^t M_s^2dM_s + \int_0^t M_sds 
\end{align}

and therefore $\int_0^t M_s^2 dM_s = \frac{M_s^3}{3} - \int_0^t M_sds$. Whereupon the second question simplifies :
$$
E\left[(1+M_t^2)\int_0^t M_s^2dM_s\right] = E\left[(1+M_t^2)\left(\frac{M_s^3}{3} - \int_0^t M_sds\right)\right]\\ 
= E\left[(1+M_t^2)\frac{M_s^3}{3}\right] - E\left[(1+M_t^2)\int_0^t M_sds\right]$$

Now, for the first one, write $M_t = (M_t-M_s)+M_s$, expand out and use independence and stationarity of increments.

For the second one, we need to use *Fubini*, because a non-negative integrand is not present. However, it is not difficult to show that $$\int_0^t E\left[|(1+M_t^2)||M_s|\right]ds < \infty$$

using independence of increments : $$(1+M_t^2)M_s = M_s + M_s(M_t-M_s)^2 + (M_s)^3 + 2(M_s)^2(M_t-M_s)$$ and therefore by the triangle inequality and independence $$E\left[|(1+M_t^2)||M_s|\right] \leq E[|M_s|] + E[|M_s|]E[|M_t-M_s|^2]+E[|M_s|^3] + 2E[|M_s^2|]E[|M_t-M_s|] $$

Now, one can use scaling, reduce to the standard normal and show that the RHS is a polynomial in $s$ and $t$, whose integral from $0$ to $t$ is then obviously finite.

Once we use Fubini, then again independence of increments, as shown in part $1$, completes the answer.

---

On other ways to evaluate these : I am not so sure. The stage is still a very basic one, in the sense that we aren't using anything beyond the definition of the Brownian motion, and the Ito formula. I thought some kind of Stochastic Fubini might work for the second part (it is a theorem that allows an exchange of an Ito and a Lebesgue integral) but I think it overcomplicates the situation, so doesn't really count.